# How can I export oracle database remotely?

Tags: database, oracle, ubuntu, export

I have been given oracle database credentilas as `read/write` only user.

Now for my experimenting stuff I want to export the data from `oracle` server to local `VM`.

I tried copy and inserting tables into `postgres` using pentaho but that failed.

Is there any way I can export that oracle data and insert in locally?

Can I install some free oracle on ubuntu and then I can do something to get that data?

I don't know oracle much

Comment: What failed?  Did you get an error?  What error?  Are you getting an error when you try to connect to the remote database?  How are you trying to connect?

Answer (score 2):

There are certainly more sophisticated ways of how to export database or a table on Oracle, but I usually export and copy the dbs with the help of `Oracle SqlDeveloper`. Just go to `Tools` menu and then select `Database Export` or `Database Copy`. Just remember that this is not the full db expot, ie. the users are not usually copied with this procedure.

The good thing is, that you may connect this tool to any database server that has Java Connector, and that makes it easy to export the data into an SQL Sever or Postgres.

If you want a more sophisticated way to export the data, check out the **Recovery Manager** (RMAN) and the `DUPLICATE` command documentation here: [RMAN on Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/rcmdupdb.htm#BRADV010)

Answer (score 0):

Use Oracle Data Pump. That is the full documentation for [Oracle 10 Data Pump](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g.php). Also you can find the documentation for 11g [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_export.htm#g1022624) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_import.htm#g1025464).

`impdp` and `expdp` work as command line. You can invoke them directly from the server or from a machine that has Oracle client installed and a connection to the server.

Considering you have limited rights on the server you will not be able to do a full database export, but I guess you do not need to; you only need to export your working schema/tables. The documentation shows how to do that: use `expdp` export only a schema and/or only some objects.

Once the export is done, you can copy the `dmp` file to any other computer (including a `VM`) and use `impdp` to import all the data to another Oracle database. You need to set up the new database before the import (import does not create it for you).